# Add a price increase on items great than or equal to with SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to create a Query that will add 15% to items greater than or equal to $20.00 but I can't seem to figure it out. Here is what I have so far. Everything is working as it should EXCEPT I don't know how to only add the 15% to those items $20.00 or more..

```
SELECT        Products.ProductID,
              Products.ProductName,
              CASE  
                WHEN (Products.CategoryID = 1) THEN 'Beverage'
                WHEN (Products.CategoryID = 2) THEN 'Sauce & Spread'
                WHEN (Products.CategoryID = 3) THEN 'Dessert'
                WHEN (Products.CategoryID = 4) THEN 'Cheese'
                WHEN (Products.CategoryID = 5) THEN 'Bread'
                WHEN (Products.CategoryID = 6) THEN 'Meat'
                WHEN (Products.CategoryID = 7) THEN 'Miscellaneous'
                WHEN (Products.CategoryID = 8) THEN 'Seafood'
                ELSE 'Unknown'
              END AS Categorys,
              Products.UnitPrice,
              FORMAT ((Products.UnitPrice * 1.15), 'N') AS NewPrice, 
              Suppliers.Name AS SupplierName
FROM          Products INNER JOIN Suppliers ON Products.SupplierID = Suppliers.SupplierID
ORDER BY ProductName
```

Comment: Could you provide some sample data and expect result?

Comment: can you give us an example of your schema and your data. 

should be simple enough but want to test before I shoot an answer over

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a case statement in your query should solve the problem.

```
SELECT    Products.ProductID,
          Products.ProductName,
          CASE  
            WHEN (Products.CategoryID = 1) THEN 'Beverage'
            WHEN (Products.CategoryID = 2) THEN 'Sauce & Spread'
            WHEN (Products.CategoryID = 3) THEN 'Dessert'
            WHEN (Products.CategoryID = 4) THEN 'Cheese'
            WHEN (Products.CategoryID = 5) THEN 'Bread'
            WHEN (Products.CategoryID = 6) THEN 'Meat'
            WHEN (Products.CategoryID = 7) THEN 'Miscellaneous'
            WHEN (Products.CategoryID = 8) THEN 'Seafood'
            ELSE 'Unknown'
          END AS Categorys,
          Products.UnitPrice,
          FORMAT (( CASE WHEN Products.UnitPrice > 20 THEN Products.UnitPrice * 1.15 ELSE Products.UnitPrice END), 'N') AS NewPrice, 
          Suppliers.Name AS SupplierName
FROM          Products INNER JOIN Suppliers ON Products.SupplierID = Suppliers.SupplierID
ORDER BY ProductName
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with a `CASE` or `IIF`

```
SELECT    Products.ProductID,
          Products.ProductName,
          Products.UnitPrice,
          ...
          AdjPrice = iif(Products.UnitPrice > 20, Products.unitPrice * 1.15, products.UnitPrice)

FROM          Products INNER JOIN Suppliers ON Products.SupplierID = Suppliers.SupplierID
ORDER BY ProductName
```